# Excel Codemodule properties

Tags: c#, excel, interop, vba

I got a problem trying to retrieve name property of a codemodule from code (C#).
When I alt+f11 my excel file I have the following:
Chart1
Sheet2
Sheet3
ThisWorkbook

When displaying properties for these, they have following properties
(Name): Chart1
Name: Pass Rate

What I want to do is access the property "Name" from C#. Is this possible? All I seem te be able to retrieve is "(Name)".
Using interop 11.0.0.0 (office 2003)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the name of the worksheet

```
MessageBox.Show(ws.Name) ;
```

and this will give you the Code Name of the worksheet

```
MessageBox.Show(ws.CodeName) ;
```

**Note**: `ws` above is your worksheet object.